# File.Exists(file) is false but file exist

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm add a file in one controller and in another controller I want check if the file is exist. I' using `File.Exist(file)`, but it's always false, even if the file exist...

I adding file, and image is added successful.

```
if ((image!= null & image.ContentLength > 0))
                    {
                        string name = event.EventId.ToString() + ".jpg";

                        var fileName = name;
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Plakaty"), fileName);
                        plakat.SaveAs(path);
                    }
```

I'm checking in another controller if this file exist:

```
string file = "~/App_Data/Plakaty/" + wyd.EventId.ToString() + ".jpg";

            ViewBag.file_exist = System.IO.File.Exists(file); //always is false
```

And my View: (It's returning only "No file")

```
 @if (ViewBag.file_exist == true)
        {
            <p>File exist</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>No file</p>
        }
```

Comment: You didn't call Server.MapPath in the other controller - won't this mean the path to your file won't be correct?

Comment: @Charleh: I think you should post this as an answer.

Comment: Obama needs the points :)

Comment: @Charleh No no i didn't see your comment, sorry :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do the `Server.MapPath` again when checking the file and do the forward slash.

```
string file = Server.MapPath("~") + @"\App_Data\Plakaty\" 
    + wyd.EventId.ToString() + ".jpg";

ViewBag.file_exist = System.IO.File.Exists(file ); //always is false
```

Comment: Are you sure about the forward slash, afaik the WinApi can also handle `/` at most places

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to write `Server.MapPath` when checking if file exist

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked permissions?

The Exists method returns false if any error occurs while trying to determine if the specified file exists. This can occur in situations that raise exceptions such as passing a file name with invalid characters or too many characters, a failing or missing disk, or if the caller does not have permission to read the file. [See documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx)

However most likely is what @Obama answered about the path being wrong as you didn't call Server.MapPath